# Sort files and folders based on when they were Last Opened

Tags: windows-10, file-management

I know there is a question already but I am not able to use it in Windows 10. I have referred to other sites on the Internet and have got a proper Date Accessed column.

But the column doesn't update itself!

I mean the dates get updated efficiently but the column doesn't get sorted out as the last accessed date change for files.

If I view a file dated 5 days prior and open it today, the file's position does not change even after refreshing!!

How to solve this? Is there any other way to get files *sorted* based on Last Access Date ?

[image]
[image]
[image]

BRACKET - shows where sorting got wrong

Comment: Just to make sure that we have understand you correctly, @Sristy: you _have_ sorted your files based on the _Date Accessed_ column after displaying it, right? We mean, you _have_ clicked on its header in order to select the ascending or descending order?

Comment: You need to *modify* the file to update the date of said file.  Windows sorts files by the modification date, not the access date.

Comment: @DOBRESCU_Mihai Yes I have sorted by clicking on the header. My files are sorted basically on the basis of the modified date in the *Date Accessed* columns except for the ones which have different accessed date wrt the modified date have changed Accessed date but still remain sorted as Date modified. **I am adding a pic**

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the protocol to answer my own question. But I got this solved by trial and error while going through different sorting options.SO, I am posting it for someone else  who has also faced this and not been able to solve it.

Turns out Windows 10 has an option **Group by** in the drop-down menu available on right-clicking in a folder.

[image]

My 'group by' was set on to be sorted by 'Date Modified'.I changed it to 'Date Accessed' and it works fine now.